# Displaying LLVMTypeRef object using LLVM C API functions

Tags: llvm

I am trying to debug my code which is a C language parser in Bison, to generate LLVM IR. I am using LLVM C API functions. I am looking for something to display my **LLVMTypeRef** object since the LLVMDumpValue(LLVMValueRef) only works with LLVMValueRef objects.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C API is definitely limited relative to the C++ API. I haven't tried it myself, but if dumping a value includes its type then creating an undef value for the type and dumping the value should be good enough for debugging purposes. That would just be

```
LLVMDumpValue(LLVMGetUndef(theTypeRef));
```

Comment: :Thank you, but using this just gives me 'i32 undef' and I guess typecasting it as undef to use the DumpValue function overwrites the original Type of my ValueRef variable and gives me the undef value.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying. If you have a value, why don't you just dump that? If it prints `i32 undef` then that means the argument to `LLVMGetUndef` would have been a reference to the `i32` type.

Comment: Ya. I apologize. I guess I don't need anything else. I can just dump the value.